# Log4j2 dynamically logs not getting created at runtime

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

log4j2.xml file dynamically gets created at runtime through java program.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="error">
        <Appenders>
            <RollingRandomAccessFile
                name="Application" immediateFlush="false"
                fileName="logs/FixGatewayLogs/Application.log"
                append="true"
                filePattern="logs/FixGatewayLogs/Application-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%d %-5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
                </Policies>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="max"
                    max="20" />
            </RollingRandomAccessFile>
            <RollingRandomAccessFile name="FirstUser"
                immediateFlush="false"
                fileName="logs/FixAcceptorLogs/FirstUser.log"
                append="true"
                filePattern="logs/FixAcceptorLogs/FirstUser-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%d %F - %m%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
                </Policies>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="max"
                    max="20" />
            </RollingRandomAccessFile>
            <RollingRandomAccessFile name="SecondUser"
                immediateFlush="false"
                fileName="logs/FixAcceptorLogs/SecondUser.log"
                append="true"
                filePattern="logs/FixAcceptorLogs/SecondUser-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%d %F - %m%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
                </Policies>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="max"
                    max="20" />
            </RollingRandomAccessFile>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <AsyncLogger name="Application" level="debug"
                includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="Application" />
            </AsyncLogger>
            <AsyncLogger name="FirstUser" level="debug"
                includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="FirstUser" />
            </AsyncLogger>
            <AsyncLogger name="SecondUser" level="debug"
                includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="SecondUser" />
            </AsyncLogger>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

Main class

```
public class CreateLog4jApplication {

        static GenerateLog4j generateLog4j = new GenerateLog4j();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                createLog4jFile();
                //System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile","./src/main/resources/log4j2.xml");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("CreateLog4jApplication Main Exception : " + e);
            }
         }

        public static void createLog4jFile() {
            try{
                // Create instance of OPTopicListener
                System.out.println("run() of CreateLog4jApplication");

                List<String> initiatorList = new ArrayList<String>();
                initiatorList.add("First");

                generateLog4j.generateLog4j2XMLFile(initiatorList);

                //((org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(true)).reconfigure();

                Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("First");

                logger.info("Enter First File");

                System.out.println("After Logger add First file");

                Thread.sleep(5000);

                initiatorList.add("Second");

                generateLog4j.generateLog4j2XMLFile(initiatorList);

                //((org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(true)).reconfigure();

                Logger logger1 = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Second");

                logger1.info("Enter Second File");

                System.out.println("After Logger add Second file");

                // This prevents program exit
                CountDownLatch  shutdownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                shutdownLatch.await();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("run() of CreateLog4jApplication Exception : " + e);
            }       
        }

    }
```

GenerateLog4j class

```
public class GenerateLog4j {
public void generateLog4j2XMLFile(List<String> initiatorList) {
    try {
        System.out.println("InitiatorList : " + initiatorList + " " + initiatorList.size());

        File       fileForDelete    = new File("src/main/resources/log4j2.xml");
        fileForDelete.delete();

        File       fileForWrite     = new File("src/main/resources/log4j2.xml");
        FileWriter fileWriterObject = new FileWriter(fileForWrite, true);


        fileWriterObject.write("<?xml version=" + "\"1.0\"" + " " + "encoding=" + "\"UTF-8\"" + "?>" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fileWriterObject.write("<Configuration status="+ "\""+ "error" +"\"" +">" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fileWriterObject.write("<Appenders>" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        fileWriterObject.close();

        String beginString       = "FIX.4.4";
        String tradesAcceptorID  = "FIX_44_ACCEPTOR_TR";


        // Iterate through the List and create entry for each Appender in XML file 
        for(int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < (initiatorList.size() + 1); fileIndex++) {
            String appName     = null;
            String filePath    = null;
            String filePattern = null;
            String pattern     = null;
            String logLevel    = null;

            if(fileIndex == 0) { // FixGateway.log
                appName  = "OrderProcessorApplication";
                filePath = "logs/FixGatewayLogs/" + appName + ".log";
                filePattern = "logs/FixGatewayLogs/" + appName +"-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz";
                pattern  = "%d %-5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n";
                logLevel = "trace";

                writeAppenderToLog4j2XMLFile(appName, filePath, filePattern, pattern, logLevel);
            }
            else { //Initiator
                // Create entry for Trades Session in XML file
                //appName = initiatorList.get(fileIndex - 1) + "_TR";
                appName = initiatorList.get(fileIndex-1);
                //filePath = "logs/FixAcceptorLogs/" + beginString + "-" + tradesAcceptorID + "-" + appName + ".log";
                filePath = "logs/FixAcceptorLogs/" + appName + ".log";
                filePattern = "logs/FixAcceptorLogs/" + appName +"-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz";
                pattern  = "%d %F - %m%n";
                logLevel = "trace";

                writeAppenderToLog4j2XMLFile(appName, filePath, filePattern, pattern, logLevel);
            }
        }


        File       fileForWriteOne     = new File("src/main/resources/log4j2.xml");
        FileWriter fileWriterObjectOne = new FileWriter(fileForWriteOne, true);

        fileWriterObjectOne.write("</Appenders>" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fileWriterObjectOne.write("<Loggers>" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        fileWriterObjectOne.close();


        // Iterate through the List and create entry for each Logger in XML file
        for(int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < (initiatorList.size() + 1); fileIndex++) {
            String appName  = null;
            String logLevel = null;

            if(fileIndex == 0) { // OrderProcessorApplication.log
                appName  = "OrderProcessorApplication";
                logLevel = "trace";

                writeLoggerToLog4j2XMLFile(appName, logLevel);
            }
            else { // Initiator
                // Create entry for Trades Session in XML file
                appName = initiatorList.get(fileIndex-1);
                logLevel = "trace";

                writeLoggerToLog4j2XMLFile(appName, logLevel);      
            }
        }

        File       fileForWriteTwo     = new File("src/main/resources/log4j2.xml");
        FileWriter fileWriterObjectTwo = new FileWriter(fileForWriteTwo, true);

        fileWriterObjectTwo.write("</Loggers>"+ System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fileWriterObjectTwo.write("</Configuration>"+ System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        // Close file handle
        fileWriterObjectTwo.close();

        System.out.println("generateLog4j2XMLFile Completed.");
     }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception In generateLog4j2XMLFile: " + e);
    }
}

public void writeLoggerToLog4j2XMLFile(String appName, String logLevel) {
    try {
        File       fileForWrite  = new File("src/main/resources/log4j2.xml");
        FileWriter fileWriterObject = new FileWriter(fileForWrite, true);

        fileWriterObject.write("<AsyncLogger name="+"\""+ appName +  "\"" +" " +"level="+"\"" + logLevel + "\""+" "+"includeLocation="+"\"true\""+" "+ "additivity="+"\"false\""+">"+ System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fileWriterObject.write("<AppenderRef ref="+"\"" + appName +"\"" + "/>" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fileWriterObject.write("</AsyncLogger>"+ System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        fileWriterObject.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception In writeLoggerToLog4j2XMLFile : " + e);
    }
}

public void writeAppenderToLog4j2XMLFile(
        String appName, String filePath, String filePattern, String pattern, String logLevel) { 
        try {
            File       fileForWrite  = new File("src/main/resources/log4j2.xml");
            FileWriter fileWriterObject = new FileWriter(fileForWrite, true);

            String fileRollOverSize = "100 MB";
            String maxNumberOfFiles = "20";  

            fileWriterObject.write("<RollingRandomAccessFile name=" + "\"" + appName + "\"" + " immediateFlush=" + "\""  + "false" + "\"" + " fileName=" + "\""+ filePath +"\""+" "+ "append=" + "\"true\"" +" "+ "filePattern=" + "\"" + filePattern + "\">"+ System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            fileWriterObject.write("<PatternLayout>" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            fileWriterObject.write("<Pattern>" + pattern + "</Pattern>" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            fileWriterObject.write("</PatternLayout>" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

            fileWriterObject.write("<Policies>" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            fileWriterObject.write("<SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="+"\"" + fileRollOverSize + "\""+ "/>" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            fileWriterObject.write("</Policies>" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            fileWriterObject.write("<DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="+"\"max\""+" "+"max="+"\"" + maxNumberOfFiles + "\""+"/>"+ System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            fileWriterObject.write("</RollingRandomAccessFile>" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

            fileWriterObject.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception In writeAppenderToLog4j2XMLFile: " + e);
        }
    }
```

}

Maven dependencies

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lmax/disruptor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
         </dependency>
```

When one user is added into xml file through code, log file gets created but when second user gets added dynamically through code, log file doesn't gets created.

NOTE: There are two different folders under logs. One for FixGateway another for FixAcceptor.

I have tried searching out the issue through google & other blogs but no improvement in eliminating this error.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? Is there some exception being thrown? Do you reach the line that should delete the first file? Does it work?

Comment: @RoyShahaf first file shouldn't get deleted. It should keep on continuing its work. No matter how many more appender gets added. It should continue its work. Same with second appender. If 3rd appender gets added same work and so on.

Comment: Your code says otherwise. “Generate...” method starts with the deletion of an existing file followed by writing the new file. Am I missing something?

Comment: Log4j xml file is deleted so that when the next time Database increments the appenders, it should completely reload the new xml file with existing & newly added appenders. The log files should be as it is. Only the xml file should replace with new appenders if exists.

Comment: When I asked if you reach the line where the first file is deleted I meant the log4j xml. And you still haven’t answered any of my questions. Do you want help?

Comment: Yes it gets deleted and creates a new xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making things harder on yourself than you need to be. Log4j2 provides the [RoutingAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) which can be used to [dynamically write to separate log files](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files) without modifying your configuration file at all.

I created a simple example using some of your configuration to illustrate how you can do what you want without programmatically modifying the configuration file.

Here is a class containing a `main` method that we'll use to run log4j2:

```
package pkg;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

public class Log4j2DiffFilePerUserMain {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();
    private static final Logger USER_LOG = LogManager.getLogger("Users");

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ThreadContext.put("userId", "user1");
        LOG.info("Now generating user1 log entry");
        USER_LOG.info("This should appear in user1 log file");

        ThreadContext.put("userId", "user2");
        LOG.info("Now generating user2 log entry");
        USER_LOG.info("This should appear in user2 log file");
    }
}
```

Notice how the `main` calls `ThreadContext.put` twice. This simulates having different users executing the code. Also note that there are two loggers - one for the "Application" and one for the "Users". Based on your configuration I believe you wanted to keep these separate.

Here is the log4j2.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile
            name="Application" immediateFlush="false"
            fileName="logs/FixGatewayLogs/Application.log"
            append="true"
            filePattern="logs/FixGatewayLogs/Application-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %-5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="max"
                max="20" />
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
        <Routing name="UsersAppender">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:userId}">
                <Route>
                    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="user-${ctx:userId}"
                        immediateFlush="false"
                        fileName="logs/FixAcceptorLogs/${ctx:userId}.log"
                        append="true"
                        filePattern="logs/FixAcceptorLogs/${ctx:userId}-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
                        <PatternLayout>
                            <Pattern>%d %F - %m%n</Pattern>
                        </PatternLayout>
                        <Policies>
                            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
                        </Policies>
                        <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="max"
                            max="20" />
                    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Application" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="Users" level="debug"
            includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="UsersAppender" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

As you can see I've used the `RoutingAppender` very similarly to how it was used in the [log4j2 FAQ page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files). It uses the `userId` context variable to dynamically decide which log to send messages to.

Running the above code and configuration generates 3 files in 2 folders:

[image]

The user1.log file contains: 
`2018-09-18 20:12:42,482  - This should appear in user1 log file`

The user2.log file contains: 
`2018-09-18 20:12:42,485  - This should appear in user2 log file`

Finally, the Application log contains:

```
2018-09-18 20:12:42,480 INFO  [main] (Log4j2DiffFilePerUserMain.java:14) - Now generating user1 log entry
2018-09-18 20:12:42,485 INFO  [main] (Log4j2DiffFilePerUserMain.java:19) - Now generating user2 log entry
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing there, expecially with

```
File fileForDelete = new File("src/main/resources/log4j2.xml");
```

Anyway, you can use `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfigLocation(URI)` to replace the current config with a new one:

```
((LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false)).setConfigLocation(newUri);
```

I'm guessing your code seems to work the first time because you replace the xml file *before* log4j2 is initialised - if you log any message before calling `createLog4jFile()`, I bet it will stop tricking you into believing it works.

Programmatic configuration might suit your use case better than the... hack you are currently using - see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html for some pointers.

PS: if you have `log4j-slf4j-imp` as a dependency, you won't need `slf4j-api` (it will be pulled as a transitive dependency by `log4j-slf4j-imp`)